# how can i programmatically check whether an address is multicast or broadcast?

Tags: networking, multicast, broadcasting

Given an address on which to listen for incoming data, I want to be able to set the proper socket options to listen for incoming data via broadcast or multicast depending on the address I am given. I know multicast adheres to a certain range, so is checking that the address falls within the range from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255 sufficient to distinguish this or could a broadcast address fall within that range?

Comment: You google it: http://bradhedlund.com/2007/11/21/identifying-ethernet-multicast/

Comment: The addresses there don't seem to be ip (dotted quad) addresses though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can simply check the first octet of the IPv4 address, if it starts with `1110`, it is an IPv4 multicast address. Beware of host vs network byte ordering when checking an IPv4 address represented in binary.